# Getting the top K item from two sorted arrays without combine them

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to get the greatest K element from two sorted arrays without merging them. My code uses a divide and conquer algorithm, I am trying to divide the two arrays from the middle element and after that I check if the array one of the middle is greater than the other I shift the end of the array to the middle and I decrease the k by the middle and I am shifting the other array from  it's start to the middle.

My problem is with large inputs, which result in a stack overflow exception. I don't know why but I think it's because the statement where I shifted the start of the array to the middle if the subtraction of the middle and the length of array is greater than K and I can't solve it.

Can anyone do me a favor and help me please?

```
public static int GetKthItem(int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int N, int M, int K, 
int start1, int start2, int end1, int end2){
if (end1 + end2 == K)
{
    return Math.Max(arr1[0], arr2[0]);
}

if (end1 + end2 + 1 == K)
{
    return Math.Min(arr1[0], arr2[0]);
}

if (start1 == end1 && K > 0)
{
    K--;
    if (K > end2 - start2)
        return arr2[start2];
    else
        return arr2[end2 - K];
}
else if (start2 == end2 && K > 0)
{
    K--;

    if (K > end1 - start1)
        return arr1[start1];
    else
        return arr1[end1 - K];
}

if (K == 0)
{
    return Math.Max(arr1[end1], arr2[end2]);
}

int mid1 = (end1 - start1) / 2;
int mid2 = (end2 - start2) / 2;

if (arr2[mid2] >= arr1[mid1])
{
    if (end2 - mid2 <= K)
    {
        return GetKthItem(arr1, arr2, N, M, (K - (end2 - mid2)), mid1, 
            start2, end1, mid2);
    {
    else
    {
        return GetKthItem(arr1, arr2, N, M, K, mid1, start2, end1, end2);
    }
}
else
{
    if (end1 - mid1 <= K)
    {
        return GetKthItem(arr1, arr2, N, M, (K - (end1 - mid1)), start1, 
            mid2, mid1, end2);
    {
    else
    {
        return GetKthItem(arr1, arr2, N, M, K, start1, mid2, end1, end2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The arrays are pre-sorted?

Comment: There may also be some insight into the answers to this question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/194646/34408

Comment: An overflowing stack is one of the consequences of deep recursion.  Unless the function is amenable to tail call recursion optimization, it's often better to come up with some sort of iterative equivalent to the recursive algorithm.

Comment: Why did you undo the formatting that removed horizontal scrolling? Now people have to scroll horizontally AND vertically to read it. Normally code should be formatted so no horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Comment: You might take a look at the third example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-th-element-two-sorted-arrays/), which implements this in C++

Comment: sorry it's my first post here I removed it by mistake I am trying to reformat it thank you for helping me:)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid merging them? What is the expected value of K? For smallish values of K, I suspect taking the highest K values from each array, concat, sort then take the highest K is simple, easy to understand and reasonably performant.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the two arrays are already sorted and you need to get the greatest K elements. 
You can have 2 pointers P1 and P2.
P1 = Last element of Array 1 [As already sorted will be last element]
P2 = Last element of Array 2

then

```
result[] -- new result array
index = 0 
while(index<k){
   if (Arr1[P1] > Arr2[P2]){
     result[index] = Arr1[P1]
     P1--
   } else {
     result[index] = Arr2[P2]
     P2--
   }
   index++
}
```